# ECLIPSE NEON WITH MAVEN PLUGIN. CompilerMojo ERROR ON COMPILING

Tags: maven, m2e, eclipse-neon

I am starting a little web project with MAVEN PLUGIN on ECLIPSE NEON.
I am using:

1. -LINUX MINT 17.3;
2. -jdk1.8.0_92;
3. -apache-maven-3.3.9.

This is the prompt on mvn -version:

*Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /home/filippo/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_92, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-38-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"*

This is PATH variable:

*/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin:/home/filippo/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin*

This is JAVA_HOME variable:

*/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_92*

On ECLIPSE NEON, I created:

1. a new MAVEN PROJECT
2. a MODULE from *org.apache.maven.archetypes – maven-archetype-quickstart*
3. a MODULE from *maven-archetype-webapp*

This is the POM.XML of the module PROJECT

[POM.XML of the module maven project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFyah.jpg)
This is the POM.XML of the web module PROJECT

[POM.XML of the web module maven project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hspfi.jpg)
During Maven compilation, a BUILD FAILURE occures becouse the **Type org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo not present**.

Belowe the log with DEBUG option of the compilation. 
Why this problem? Could you help me? Thank you....
Filippo.

```
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4
[DEBUG]   Included: log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.2
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo not present
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:143)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete the content of your local repository (and then tried again)?

Comment: Yes. Does not work. It seems the CompilerMojo class does not exists on maven

Comment: The first things you should check does the compilation on command working without any issue so really console and do `mvn clean package` ?

Comment: The Maven-Compiler-Plugin should furthermore be updated to 3.5.1.

Comment: I deleted the content of local repository, and the compilation is OK! I am a beginners using MAVEN, and would ask you how can do update the  MAVEN-COMPILER-PLUGIN...

Comment: You need to define the version in your pom (or your parent-pom), then the correct version is downloaded for you.

Comment: Same problem after moving to Eclipse Neon, seems to be real bug based off of this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499687